# Preventing second level menu from collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu created for my website. The first level is menu is fine but the problem is with second level menu. I have positioned the second level menu a little down from the top so when I start to move the mouse down the menu gets collapsed. I want that gap to be filled without moving the second level menu from its current position.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CfVyQ/). Move you mouseover the "My Profile" link then slowly move down your mouse to the second level menu. The result is that the menu gets collapsed because of the little space in between the parent `li` and the child `ul`. How can I fix that error?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu nav ul li").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
    }, function (e) {
        $(this).children("ul").slideUp();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <div class="welcome_area">
        <p>Welcome, <b><a href="profile.php">Arkam Gadet</a> </b>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">My Questions</a>

                        </li>
                        <li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a href="#">Settings</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="inbox.php">Inbox</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Notifications</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 1px #bbb;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
    color: #f79a1d;
}
.welcome_area {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.menu nav > ul {
    position: relative;
    padding:0px;
}
.menu nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
.menu nav ul li a {
    padding: 2px;
}
.menu nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #000;
}
.menu nav > ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 40px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 3px #bbb;
}
.menu nav > ul li > ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `slideUp` in a timeout and clear it if you hover in again before it runs like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t;
    $(".menu nav ul li").hover(function (e) {
        if(t) clearTimeout(t);
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
    }, function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        t=setTimeout(function(){$this.children("ul").slideUp();},250);

    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CfVyQ/2/

Comment: just a note, hovering over another li will clear the timeout and the menu will never collapse

Comment: @koala_dev what can I do then?

Comment: @koala_dev: Very true, the code is meant as inspiration for a full solution that will meet the OP's requirements

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: you should only clear the timeout when hovering over the second level menu

Comment: Or just hide all siblings sub-menus when hovering over another li